# Find the index of a string that begins with

Tags: c#, observablecollection

I'm developing a WPF with C# and .NET Framework 4.6.1.

I was using this line of code:

```
codesRead.IndexOf(string.Format("{0} OK", lastCode));
```

`codesRead` is a `private readonly ObservableCollection<string>`.

It was working very fine when I was using these strings `"code1 OK"`.

Now I have changed the strings with these ones `"code1 OK - 23.0005 ms"` and now it always returns `-1`.

How can I find the index of a string that begins with `"code1 OK"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the `Find` clause to get the element and then search for it with `IndexOf`. Here is a small console application to illustrate this:

```
List<string> asd = new List<string> 
    { "code5 OK - 234", "code2 OK - 234", "code1 OK - 234", "code4 FAIL - 234" };

int index = asd.IndexOf(asd.Find(x => x.StartsWith("code1")));

Console.WriteLine(index);
```

It will return `-1` if the element does not exist

EDIT:  Sorry, I did not read accurately enough your post apparently.
If you are using an `ObservableCollection` I would suggest to use `FirstOrDefault` to search for the item. Here is an example with a negative outcome:

```
ObservableCollection<string> qwe = new ObservableCollection<string>() 
    { "code5 OK - 234", "code2 OK - 234", "code7 OK - 234" };

int index = qwe.IndexOf(qwe.FirstOrDefault(x => x.StartsWith("code1")));

Console.WriteLine(index);
```

Comment: @Default lol thank you, I tried it first with `Where`, but then decided to do it with `Find`, but somehow my brain did not follow my fingers... Thank you for the reminder. I changed it

Comment: I have had to use `Where` because `ObservableCollection` doesn't have Find (or I haven't which dll I have to add).

Comment: @VansFannel sorry, I did not read carefully enough. You can use `FirstOrDefault` it will have the same result as `Find` in a `List`. I always forget that this method is missing in `ObservableCollection`. See my edit

Comment: As for the previous one you could have used `FindIndex` for that but only defined for `List<T>` which is not related to `ObservableCollection` as you noticed.

Comment: @Sehnsucht please copy paste my posted `List` example into a console application, remove `"code1"` from the List, compile and run it...

Comment: @Sehnsucht please also try the same with the `ObservableCollection`. I don't get any exceptions.... Was that the reason for the downvote?

Comment: @MongZhu my bad, I looked at the wrong `IndexOf` too focused on the string, I looked at `string.IndexOf` instead of `IndexOf` for collections, sorry I'm hiding far away

Comment: @Sehnsucht :) no worries. I also came up at first with a method from the wrong class ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can first project the indexes with the item then search for the element(s) you want and finally get thoses indexes.

```
var result =
    source
    .Select ((item, index) => new { item, index })
    .Where (tmp => tmp.item.StartsWith ("theStart"))
    .Select (tmp => tmp.index); // if you just want the indexes
```

You can replace `Where` with `First[OrDefault]` or `Single[OrDefault]` if needed.
You can replace `StartsWith` with `IndexOf` and test for equality with 0.

If you're not interested in the value but just the indexes, you can directly do the `StartsWith` / `IndexOf` in the first `Select`

```
var result =
    source
    .Select (item, index) => new { index, isValid = item.StartsWith ("theStart") })
    .Where (tmp => tmp.isValid)
    .Select (tmp => tmp.index);
```